Where can I find the "increase shadow memory" option (Shadow Pool)?
I ran into this problem – additional light sources don't cast shadows. There’s no error message, they just don’t cast shadows! I searched the entire internet, and people say you need to increase the shadow pool, but where is it in version 4.1? Where did they move it?



Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. Could you edit your post and translate all text to English? If you are not comfortable writing it yourself, feel free to use any automated online translation service.
